# Cannot publish my .net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, publish

I have a made a website in a .Net core webapplication but cannot seem to publish this.

If I publish this to a folder and drag the contents of that folder inside IIS it works on my localhost.
When I try to put this on a server it bugs out.

When I looked inside my published folder it's full of dll's and 2 .pdb files. and an .exe file.
It does contain a web.config file but there are no views or index.html / index.cshtml.

Any idea? Been stuck on this on for the past 2 days.

When I publish this to a folder this is what I get;
[image]

And inside wwwroot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Configure below things carefully when published an application in server.[image: Publish Configuration]

My application also contains no views or index.html / index.cshtml.

[image: Published Folder]

I have deployed into IIS in server and it is working fine.

Comment: This works fine in IIS localhost for me. I have called multiple times with this company now, apparently they haven't configred their system properly so it can't load my project.